# Group only if there are rows to be grouped

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like your assistance in solving an issue which I am battling now for days without even coming close to a solution. Unfortunately, I have already posted my issue and was not able to make any improvement with the suggestion delivered.

What I would like to achieve is somewhat attained by `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` with the possibility of `CASE WHEN` but whatever I do I am not getting to what I desire.

What I want to achieve is a `GROUP BY` **only when** the contents of the group exceed 3 rows and leave the individual items i.e. **not grouped** when group is less than or equal to three.

## EXAMPLE

```
ID     DESC    VAL1   VAL 2   VAL 3    
1      DESC1    2       2       4    
2      DESC2    2       2       4     
3      DESC3    2       2       4    
4      DESC4    2       2       4     
5      DESC5    1       1       2      
6      DESC6    1       1       2
```

`GROUP BY` will be through *VAL1*, *VAL2*, *VAL 3* through the following

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY VAL1,VAL2,VAL3
```

This will yield the following:

```
ID     DESC    VAL1   VAL 2   VAL 3    
1      DESC1    2       2       4    
5      DESC5    1       1       2
```

However what I need is the following:

```
ID     DESC    VAL1   VAL 2   VAL 3    
1      DESC1    2       2       4    
5      DESC5    1       1       2      
6      DESC6    1       1       2
```

Can this be achieved with `GROUP BY`, what I think of is subquery but I cannot manage. Your assistance will be very much appreciated.

DBMS is MySQL.

Comment: It seems you never accept any answer on your questions. You might want to [learn how this site works](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It might require some minor tweaks, as I didn't test it. But i think you will get the idea.

```
Select * 
from table1 
where md5(concat(val1,val2,val3)) in (
    SELECT md5(concat(val1,val2,val3)) 
    FROM TABLE1 
    GROUP BY VAL1,VAL2,VAL3 
    having count(*) > 3) 
group by VAL1,VAL2,VAL3
union
Select * 
from table1 
where md5(concat(val1,val2,val3)) not in (
    SELECT md5(concat(val1,val2,val3)) 
    FROM TABLE1 
    GROUP BY VAL1,VAL2,VAL3 
    having count(*) > 3)
```

Comment: Why use `MD5()`?

Comment: @Barmar The first query has a GROUP BY. And it can actually work for the given sample data. But `md5()` is superfluous. And `concat(12, 3, 4)` is equal to `concat(1, 23, 4)`.

Comment: Md5 is actually not necessary here. But you could do concat(val1,'-',val2,'-',val3) to avoid the issue you mentioned.

Comment: I missed the extra `GROUP BY` (there are so many of them I got lost). You should fix your answer rather than just mention it in a comment. Use `CONCAT_WS()`.

Comment: I'd like to remove my downvote, which was based on a misreading. But I can't unless you edit the question. If you add the delimiters in `CONCAT`, I can do that.

Comment: `CONCAT` is not needed at all. You can as well just use `where (val1,val2,val3) in (
    SELECT val1,val2,val3 FROM ...)`. But then you get the next problem with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode.

Comment: @Papa zulu Thank you for the quick answer delivered. Did some tweaks to it and it worked!!. Very simple to understand and to implement in my existing code. Thanks to the guidelines. Upvote to you sir. Thank you all for the response.

Answer (score 0):

With UNION ALL, for the 2 different cases:

```
select t.* from tablename t inner join (
  select min(id) minid
  from tablename
  group by val1, val2, val3
  having count(*) > 3
) g on g.minid = t.id
union all
select * from tablename t
where (
  select count(*) from tablename 
  where val1 = t.val1 and val2 = t.val2 and val3 = t.val3
) <= 3
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ujsjzLWeQ5J3hZgj7yS5T8/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8.0, you can achieve this simply with window functions `COUNT()` and `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT id, descr, val1, val2, val3
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.*,
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY val1, val2, val3) cnt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY val1, val2, val3 ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM mytable t
) x WHERE cnt < 3 OR rn = 1
ORDER BY id
```

In the inner query, `cnt` indicates how many records have the same `val1, va2, val3` as the current one. `rn` assigns a rank to each record within groups of records having the same `val1, va2, val3`. The outer query then uses these two pieces of information to filter the relevant records.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4niJ2Ph2C9KYho6m69TC3R/0)**:

```
| id  | descr | val1 | val2 | val3 |
| --- | ----- | ---- | ---- | ---- |
| 1   | DESC1 | 2    | 2    | 4    |
| 5   | DESC5 | 1    | 1    | 2    |
| 6   | DESC6 | 1    | 1    | 2    |
```